# How to detect from client which ports are being blocked?

Tags: firewall, port

The issue I have currently is with Windows (WindowsXP --> Windows 2003) but I would be interested also in how resolving it in a linux client.

I work with a network split in several subnetworks and there is a firewall between those that is managed by the parent company. Sometimes, when troubleshooting/installing new applications, we find that it does not work due to some port being blocked, and everytime it is a lengthy process to contact the firewall people and agree for a time for a test so we replicate the action and they check the log of the firewall.

As they are pretty much overworked and I would like some more flexibility, I would like to know if there is some way to, from the client, detect attempted connections dropped or denied by the firewall (or at least, all connections from a process/to a server so we can revise them).

I have tried logging things with wireshark, but (if it is the way) I do not know what to look for in the dump. I don't think netstat or PortView would work as these connections are not established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good scanning tools like [nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html) that can show you what ports on a target system are reachable, and which are not.

Comment: The issue is not which ports are currently open but which ports should I open (or ask to be open) in order to get the issue resolved (v.g., a third party program that does not connect and for which I don't have proper documentation).

Comment: Aaaa, I see. I've always worked forward with a knowledge from documentation or other sources what ports will be needed, then scanned to see if they are reachable. If your docs are good enough, you will have to watch traffic on your client using `tcpdump` or `wireshark` or `etercap` or other similar eves dropping tools.

Comment: +1 because Wireshark is the correct answer.

Comment: Ok. Before giving you the answer: Any suggestion of what I could be looking at (some filter that shows these connections)?

Comment: I'm not a `wireshark` kind of fish, but it looks like you can capture a bunch of traffic starting before one of your attempts, then add some filters after the capture to find things directed at your target server. The packet details should show what ports were used, and you can even sort by protocal which should make it easy to drill down. In `tcpdump` I would just rig up some grep/perl stuff to see a list of ports that got hit during any given dump.

Comment: Wireshark's GUI colors dropped connections in red, making it easy. If you have only tcpdump, then you capture to a file and import it into Wireshark for easier viewing.